# Multi module hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

We're using Hiberate + Spring + Maven to implement a large web application.

The application has been partitioned into a graph of multiple Maven modules,some of which have persistence. These modules are combined as maven dependencies within the parent web app. and a couple of the modules are used standalone in other apps.

I have the following structure:

**core-module**
Contains the core services and persistence api.

**social-module** 
It's a standalone application with its own entity (Eg. Comment, Poll etc..) service and persistence api.

**social-integration** 
This should be the glue the social module to the core application and contains relashionship entities, persistence, service and controller.

**webapp** It's just a war container with the commons spring configuration and depends from all modules.

I try to use Hibernate inheritance to extends core class Project to add required relationships, but I had few problem and I don't think it's the right implementation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Project implements Serializable
{
    .....
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "social_project")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class SocialProject extends Project
{  

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", targetEntity = ProjectComment.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  protected List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>(0);

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", targetEntity = ProjectQuestion.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  protected List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>(0);

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", targetEntity = ProjectEvent.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  protected List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>(0);


  ......
}
```

So... Can I create a clean relationship between this modules without changing core application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change structure of your application using next modules:

```
social-model (or social-schema)
social-dao
social-ws (i.e. web services)
social-runtime (create result jar/war file)
```

Dependencies between modules:

```
dao depends from model module
ws depends from model and dao modules
runtime depends from all modules
```

Declare all modules in root pom. During build Maven will resolve dependencies and perform build in proper order:

```
root,model,dao,ws,runtime
```

And for example ws module will reuse xml Spring config files from dao module. Just use import directive in Spring config of ws module.